# compatibility between picinpar and hvfoat

Tags: incompatibility, picinpar

I updated recently my packages. Since this update, I have an error when I try to use the environment `figwindow` from the package `picinpar` with the package `hvfloat`.

I get the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\caption@wincaption ...caption@ContinuedFloattrue 
                                                  \fi \edef \@tempa {\expand...
l.16         },{figwindow in a text}\label{fig}]

?
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{picinpar}       
\usepackage{hvfloat}


\begin{document}

    \begin{figwindow}[1,c,{ 
            \includegraphics[width=4.0cm,draft]{example-image.png}
        },{figwindow in a text}\label{fig}]
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{figwindow}

\end{document}
```

Is it a solvable problem or should I wait a new update ?

Comment: I changed to `example-image` and added the full error message so it shows which command is undefined.

Comment: I can confirm it works in texlive 2017 and not in texlive 2018 (it's caption.sty that changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix:

I will fix this tomorrow and upload a new version of the `caption` package bundle to CTAN next week-end.

Work-around:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{picinpar}       
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\caption@ContinuedFloattrue{\caption@setflag1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{figwindow}[1,c,{ 
            \includegraphics[width=4.0cm,draft]{example-image.png}
        },{figwindow in a text}\label{fig}]
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{figwindow}

\end{document}
```

P.S.: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/38

Comment: Cool! I gain reputation on SX by fixing bugs I have introduced myself. Maybe I should produce more bugs, making my reputation skyrocketing. Reminds me of http://dilbert.com/strip/1995-11-13 and http://dilbert.com/strip/1995-11-14 .

Comment: Is there any other way to gain rep? :-)

Comment: I just uploaded a new version 2018-10-06 of the `caption` package bundle to CTAN, so it should be available on CTAN and for TeXlive and MikTeX (and hopefully other TeX distributions as well) soon.